# In Django, when using admin.StackedInline, how to thread-safely pass a request to forms' __init__?

Tags: python, django, thread-safety, django-admin

I want to pass a request to my forms in formset of StackedInline. Now I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.functional import curry


class AlbumInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = AlbumAdminForm
    model = Album
    extra = 1

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super(AlbumInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        formset.form.__init__ = curry(formset.form.__init__, request=request)
        return formset
```

This works, but is this solution thread-safe? If it's not, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be thread safe. Depending on what you want to use from an HTTP request object, you can copy it to a new HttpRequest and make it only contain thread-safe information (that is most information minus the request thread lock).

In my case, I use something like this:

```
METACOPY = ['HTTP_X_REAL_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'REMOTE_HOST', 'SERVER_NAME', 'SERVER_PORT', 'LANG', 'LANGUAGE', 'HTTP_REFERER']
def thread_safe_copy(self):
    meta = dict([(k,self.META[k]) for k in METACOPY if k in self.META and isinstance(self.META[k], str)])
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.POST = self.POST
    request.GET = self.GET
    request.user = self.user
    request.path = self.path
    request.META = meta
    ...
    return request
```

Here, I monkey-patched HttpResponse and WSGIResponse, but you can replace self with the request instance.

Comment: I'm looking for generic solution, i.e. I need whole **original** request in my forms like that we have in our views, not a copy. The one thing I still can not understand why is that can't be as easy as just pass a param to а function.

Comment: This is not that simple because the original request is tied to a thread lock (the lock is an attribute of the META data). This cannot be thread safe and this is what your question was about. You can still try to null the attribute before passing the request object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's thread safe, due to the curry which binds the request.

But since it's in the admin, so it might not matter.